# Ionic 3 - Files not found when running app in Android device

Tags: android, ionic3

I’m trying to run my app on a Tablet with Android 6. After the splashscreen is showed, the screen becomes white and nothing more happend. Using the Chrome Inspect, I found out the files are not been found. What should I do?

I’m using Ionic Version 3.19.0

**EDIT:**

- I ran the commands `ionic cordova platform add android`, then `ionic cordova build android` (although I think it isn't necessary), and then `ionic cordova run android --device`. I tried removing and re-adding the platform, but it still isn't working.

[image]

Comment: Is this happening for every file in the index.html or some specific files?

Comment: `cordova.js` is found. All the other files looking for `build/something` aren't.

Comment: Did you add the platform initially? Also you need to build for it after adding the platform.

Comment: Yes, I did it. See my edit.

Comment: Is there any error while you are testing in a app that produced in the terminal. I am not asking for web console but the terminal error that comes once you run it via a emulator or device or something

Comment: No, there's no error messages. I think some file is corrupted or missing, but even running `ionic doctor check` didn't give me answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out what the problem was. I removed the `<base href="/">` tag from the `index.html` and it started working... thanks for the attention guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the path to all your javascript files like:

```
<script src="./build/main.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="../build/main.js"></script>
```

or eventually with the absolute path of the files ( not the best idea )

Comment: also with the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

After have tried change <base href... to many different configurations, this solved to me:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.0
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest (current, latest = 5.0.0)
```

Credits:
https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/issues/451
zimprince commented on Jul 11, 2019